# Sql query returns duplicate

Tags: mysql, sql

I have executions and each execution has several images and videos, example,

table execution

```
 id |    name
 1   execution1
```

table image

```
id |   executionId | image
1          1          'path'
2          1          'path2'
```

table audio

```
id |   executionId | audio
1          1          'path3'
```

I want a query that get all the executions, with each execution having all their images like,

```
  { executions: [
         { id: 1,
           name: execution1,
           images: 'path+path2',
           audio: 'path3'
          },
         {...}
      ]
 }
```

I have this query:

```
 query = 
    "select a.id, group_concat(image.image SEPARATOR '+'), group_concat(audio.audio SEPARATOR '+') 
    from execution a 
    left join image on image.executionId = a.id 
    left join audio on audio.executionId = a.id 
    group by a.id";
```

but returns

```
  { executions: [
         { id: 1,
           name: execution1,
           images: 'path+path2',
           audio: 'path3+path3'
          },
         {...}
      ]
    }
```

Why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a 1-N (or maybe N-M) relationship in the data that is being aggregated. If there is one record in `audio` but two in `image` (or the other way aroud), you will get duplicates values in the string generated by `GROUP_CONCAT(audio ...)`.

On solution is to use `DISTINCT` to avoid duplicating data in `GROUP_CONCAT` :

```
select 
    a.id,  
    group_concat(DISTINCT image.image SEPARATOR '+'),
    group_concat(DISTINCT audio.audio SEPARATOR '+') 
from execution a 
left join image on image.executionId = a.id 
left join audio on audio.executionId = a.id 
group by a.id
```

Comment: @danielgon : yes you are right ! well I changed my answer

Comment: @danielgon : if this answer was helpful to you, please consider upvoting it as well... Thanks !